# ASP ListView Formatting

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have a item in a listView control like this

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Open") %>' />
```

The 'open' is coming from a database via linq to sql. The open can either have a value of Y, or N. I want it to say instead 'Open' or 'Closed'.

What is the best way to do this? Can I do it in the mark up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%#Eval("Open") == "Y"? "Open" : "Closed" %>
```

But if those are the only possible values, you might want to consider changing the type to a bit.